# How to call Hawkular from Vert.x

Tags: vert.x, hawkular

I want to get the metrics from vert.x with Hawkular, but I have problem.
Following the tutorial of this. http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hawkular-metrics/java/

Then, I change the code of the tutorial of vert.x
http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/

like this.

from this

```
@Before
  public void setUp(TestContext context) {
    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(MyFirstVerticle.class.getName(),
        context.asyncAssertSuccess());
  }
```

to this

```
VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions()
    .setMetricsOptions(new VertxHawkularOptions()
        .setHost("localhost")
        .setPort(8080)
        .setTenant("com.acme")
        .setAuthenticationOptions(
            new AuthenticationOptions()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setId("jdoe")
                .setSecret("password")).setEnabled(true));
vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);

  JsonObject message = new JsonObject()
      .put("id", "myapp.files.opened")
      .put("value", 7);
  vertx.eventBus().publish("metrics", message);
```

But I think I there are no changes in Hawkular.
First of all, I checked with WireShark, there looks like no connection of HTTP request of this application.
I want to know if I execute this code, can I see some change in the Hawkular Metrics?

I already checked.

- this program pass these codes.
- even though I change the Host and Port wrong one, there are no execption.

Comment: Have you enabled the metrics bridge? http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hawkular-metrics/java/#_user_defined_metrics

Comment: Thank you for advice, but in my environment it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the test process finishes before the metrics had time to get reported. I tried with your example (which looks correct beside this timing issue), and had to put a Thread.sleep of 1 second after publishing on the event bus in order to see something in Hawkular.

`curl -u jdoe:password -H "Hawkular-Tenant: com.acme" http://localhost:8080/hawkular/metrics/counters`

now gives

`[{"id":"vertx.eventbus.publishedRemoteMessages","dataRetention":14,"type":"counter","tenantId":"com.acme"},{"id":"vertx.pool.worker.vert.x-internal-blocking.queuedCount","dataRetention":14,"type":"counter","tenantId":"com.acme"},{"id":"vertx.eventbus.receivedMessages","dataRetention":14,"type":"counter","tenantId":"com.acme"}, etc.`

Comment: Thank you so much! I put a sleep, then I get the metrics!!